# infinite repeat of database rows when using function to fetch data

Tags: php

i am trying to get some rows form database (tickets table) and show on my website, i have created two functions one for running any query named `runquery` and one for reading from ticket table
here is my code:

```
    function runquery($conn , $sql )
{
    $result=mysqli_query($conn , $sql) ;
    if(!$result)
    {

        die  (mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    return $result ;
}

function get_tickets($conn)
{

    return runquery($conn , "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE userid=".$_SESSION['userid'] ) ;
}
```

here is how im using this functions

```
    <ul>
        <?php 
            $data = get_tickets($conn);
        while($ticket =mysqli_fetch_assoc(   $data )) {?>
        <li><?php echo $ticket['id'] ; ?>-<?php echo $ticket['title'] ; ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

the problem is when i put my get_tickets function directly inside mysqli_fetch_assoc like this

```
while($ticket =mysqli_fetch_assoc(get_tickets($conn)))
```

i get stuck into infinite loop but when i call get_tickets function outside mysqli_fetch_assoc like this

```
$data = get_tickets($conn);
while($ticket =mysqli_fetch_assoc(   $data ))
```

it works fine... why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep your **get_tickets($conn)** in your loop, you are gonna execute the query every iteration.
Which mean that `$ticket` is always gonna be the same value in the loop, and will keep on going.

So of course, you have to run the query once outside of the loop.